# Issues with Profiling java application using jProbe

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, jprobe

Im currently doing dynamic memory analysis, for our eclipse based application using jprobe.After starting the eclipse application and jprobe, when I try to profile the eclipse application, the application gets closed abruptly causing a Fatal error. A fatal error log file is generated. In the Fatal error log file, I could see that the PermGen space seems to be full. Below is a sample Heap summary which I got in the log file

```
Heap
def new generation   total 960K, used 8K [0x07b20000, 0x07c20000, 0x08000000)
eden space 896K,   0% used [0x07b20000, 0x07b22328, 0x07c00000)
from space 64K,   0% used [0x07c00000, 0x07c00000, 0x07c10000)
to   space 64K,   0% used [0x07c10000, 0x07c10000, 0x07c20000)
tenured generation   total 9324K, used 5606K [0x08000000, 0x0891b000, 0x0bb20000)
the space 9324K,  60% used [0x08000000, 0x08579918, 0x08579a00, 0x0891b000)
compacting perm gen  total 31744K, used 31723K [0x0bb20000, 0x0da20000, 0x2bb20000)
the space 31744K,  99% used [0x0bb20000, 0x0da1af00, 0x0da1b000, 0x0da20000)
ro space 8192K,  66% used [0x2bb20000, 0x2c069920, 0x2c069a00, 0x2c320000)
rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x2c320000, 0x2c966130, 0x2c966200, 0x2cf20000)
```

I tried to increase the permGen space, using the command -XX:MaxPermSize=512m. But that doesnt seem to work. I would like to know how to increase the PermGen size via command prompt. I would like to know if I have to go to the java location in my computer and execute the above command or should I increase the PermGen space  specifically for the eclipse application or Jprobe ?  Please advise.

Any help on this is much appreciated.